# Measure the tradeoff between accuracy and speed of algorithms

Tags: performance, algorithm, time, measurement, tradeoff

I have a group of algorithms A, B, C and D. Each of them has a specific execution time and a certain accuracy (MSE). Is there a formal way of calculating the tradeoff between the execution time (speed) and the accuracy?

For example if A has an accuracy of 0.1 and a computational time of 3s, whereas algorithm B has a better accuracy at 0.095, but needs 150s to execute. Although B performs slightly better, the tradeoff should favor A, since it takes considerably less time to execute.

Is there any equation or formal approach I can use to calculate this tradeoff?

Comment: If you are asking how you pick the 'best' one of these algorithms then that depends entirely on your requirements - for some applications accuracy is paramount regardless of speed for example.

Comment: I'm aware that this depends entirely on your application. I just want some relative measurement that I can play around with. Is there something (like a law or equation) in academic literature that can do this (more or less)? I'll then adapt it so that it fits my needs.

Comment: something like: accuracy*sqrt(speed). This already works, but I want something slightly more advanced, if possible with a reference to an academic article or book.

Comment: I think any such equation would be making assumptions about your requirements - your example is effectively saying that accuracy carries more weight than speed, someone else might have the opposite requirement so they might use sqrt(accuracy) * speed - I don't see how there could be 1 equation that covers every scenario, it would be so generic as to be useless imho

Comment: This depends too much on your actual requirements. The connection between accuracy, speed and fitness-for-purpose doesn't even have to be a continuous function: take a scenario where your answer must come within 100ms. This is often the case when user interaction is involved: the difference between a 1us response and a 100ms response is irrelevant despite there being a factor of 100000 between the two, while 200ms can be unacceptable. So the best you can do is set your own formula and explain the reasoning behind it. You'll find that trying to explain why you chose the formula helps refine it.

Comment: So in your case: why `accuracy*sqrt(speed)`? What is it in your requirements that makes you think speed should be proportional to the square of accuracy?

Comment: Imagine what might happen to a fighter jet with a fly-by-wire control system cruising at Mach 2 if you pick the one with the better accuracy but much longer compute time. Now imagine where your Neptune-bound satellite might actually end up if you pick the one that is quicker to compute, but less accurate... There is no way to provide a single universal metric to determine the answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Although this might not always be appropriate in all situations, I've found a paper that might be useful to future readers looking for a time-accuracy tradeoff. It was published by people from MIT.

*Sidiroglou-Douskos, S., Misailovic, S., Hoffmann, H., and Rinard, M. (2011). Managing Performance vs Accuracy Trade-offs with Loop Perforation. In Proceedings of the ACM SIGSOFT Symposium and the European Conference on Foundations of Software Engineering, pages 124–134. ACM.*